# My self.canvas.clear() function not working but other codes in the method run

Tags: python, kivy

This is the .kv string:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<Paint>:
     Button:
         text: 'clear'
         on_release: app.instance.cleaner()

''')
```

This is the class

```
class Paint(Widget):
    def cleaner(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        print('Cleared')
```

The print('Cleared') prints perfectly fine when the button is clicked,but self.canvas.clear() doesn't do anything

```
class MainApppp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.instance = Paint()
        return Background()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: The `clear()` method removes all instructions from the `Canvas`. If you haven't added any instructions, it will not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example it illustrates using `canvas.clear()` function to erase a widget.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_string = '''
<Paint>:
    Button:
        text: 'clear'
        on_release: 
            # root.cleaner()
            app.root.erase()

<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.1, 0.6, 0.3
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size     
            pos: self.pos

        Color:
            rgb: 0.6, 0.2, 0.1
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size     
            pos: self.center

<Background>:
    MyWidget:
        id: mywidget

    Paint:
        id: btn
'''

Builder.load_string(kv_string)


class Paint(Widget):

    def cleaner(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        print('Cleared')


class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass


class Background(BoxLayout):

    def erase(self):
        self.ids.mywidget.canvas.clear()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Widget's canvas.clear() Demo"

    def build(self):
        return Background()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Eclipse erased]

Comment: Thanks for this 

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, feel free to up vote and/or accept it, as you see fit. Thank you.